# Why did Grothendieck invent schemes when they seem at odds with his philosophy?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history

From what I understand, a scheme is basically a sheaf on $\mathbf{Ring}^{\mathrm{op}}$ equipped with an appropriate Grothendieck topology, subject to an axiom that says that schemes look locally like commutative rings. If it weren't for this axiom, the category of schemes would be a topos, and hence very well behaved. But because of this axiom, the category of schemes isn't very well-behaved; for example, it's neither complete nor cocomplete. If so, then focusing on schemes seems to run at odds with Grothendieck's philosophy that it's better to have a good category with bad objects than a bad category consisting only of good objects. What gives here?

Comment: May I dare say that it is like looking for a lost object under a street lamp just because there is light there. I would say that mathematicians are primarily concerned about "good objects", but deal with bad ones if necessary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) Schemes were invented in the early 1960s, and Grothendieck wasn't the only one involved in their development (though he is usually credited with their invention) - I think it was Serre who first defined $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ and its structure sheaf (hence affine schemes); Cartan came up with the idea of ringed spaces (at least this is what I gather from reading the excellent introduction to EGA I, Grundlehren edition). And of course, the fundamental analogy is:
schemes / affine schemes = manifolds / euclidean spaces.

2) Topos theory was invented after schemes (of course), and it is (from a geometrical point of view) essentially the unsuccessful cousin of scheme theory. Schemes brought about a revolution and made it possible to resolve, say, the Weil conjectures and Fermat's last theorem. Can you name me a problem of similar importance that was solved by topos theory? The difference between topos theory and schemes is that the latter is geometrically meaningful. As with most mathematicians, Grothendieck's best work was in his youth (schemes, motives, etale cohomology), and in his youth he truly was doing geometry, and not merely category theory. With age Grothendieck lost a bit of his creativity and he mainly cared about excessive generalisations.

3) "Grothendieck's philosophy that it's better to have a good category with bad objects than a bad category consisting only of good objects." Can you give a reference showing that this is truly due to Grothendieck?

Comment: Regarding 3, I did some Googling and it turns out Grothendieck never said this. What really happened was John Baez said it and suggested the the idea has arisen with Grothendieck. You can read John's full comment [here](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2007/12/this_weeks_finds_in_mathematic_19.html).

Comment: The notion of topos, etale cohomology and motives were invented around the same time. And some things Grothendieck cared about when he got older were actually more concrete(dessin denfant, for example).  I think the answer to the question is simply that those sheaves which dont come from  geometry are not interesting.

Comment: @Saberization more concrete than classifying vector bundles over the 2 sphere? ;) I suggest you take a look at his earlier papers..

Comment: Well, at least one can explain what dessin denfant is to a 10 year old kid. I will be impressed if you can do the same with vector bundle.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree that Grothendieck's best work was in his youth, but since your comment 3) led me to realize that actually, Grothendieck never said this, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: The definition of the scheme $\operatorname {Spec}(A)$ for an arbitrary commutative ring $A$ is due to Grothendieck  **and to nobody else** (it was first written-up by Grothendieck-Dieudonné in EGA 1). Section 15 of the preface you mention explains that the idea of defining an algebraic variety as a ringed space is due to Serre (which is true), but Serre only considered rings which were algebras of finite type over an algebraically closed field. It was Cartier who **suggested**  to Grothendieck that he consider arbitrary rings $A$ but it was Grothendieck alone who implemented  that suggestion.

Comment: Is it me or there's a slight nuance of "category theory isn't real Mathematics " in your answer?

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I have no opinion about that. Category theory certainly isn't real geometry...

Comment: And yet you claim that Grothendieck cared about "excessive generalization" and that topos theory brings nothing to Mathematics. Both points are quite debatable. There isn't only geometry out there. 

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I am not saying that it brings nothing to mathematics, I am saying that it is irrelevant to 99% of all algebraic geometry results. Name one important result in algebraic geometry for which topos theory is unavoidable. I knowalgebraic geometers who were plenary lecturers at ICM and who don't even know what a topos is. I think that says everything.

Comment: There is no need to start a flame, but I guess there are less people in topos theory that ignore the definition of a scheme than there are people in algebraic geometry ignoring what a topos is. And I could say that "this says everything" even though I don't know precisely *what*. I feel topos theory was invented to do algebraic geometry, but that's not the reason why it survived. So? What is your point? [cntd]

Comment: [ctnd] I feel the OP asked a question about Grothendieck philosophy in doing Mathematics, not only about algebraic geometry and scheme theory. Algebraic geometry is a part of Mathematics; the philosophy according to which Grothendieck wanted to reshape it is totally different pair of shoes.

Comment: @FoscoLoregian I know what it says. It says that schemes are much more fundamental and useful than topos theory. One cannot avoid them in algebraic geometry. Topos theory was invented for algebraic geometry, but no one in algebraic geometry does topos theory now. I check the math.AG every day, and I don't even remember having seen a paper using topos theory. They may be useful for other purposes, but not for geometry. This is what I am saying.